# What are the chances of a football team being drawn away in a cup game 15 out of 17 times.

Tags: probability

Info about the question -In UK cup football all the teams names are put in a pot and drawn out one at a time. The team picked out of the pot first are the home team and the next team is their opponents and they are the away team.

The next team is drawn and they are the home team and the next team are their oppontents who will be the away team. And so on until all the remaining teams are out of the pot. The away teams then have to travel to their opponents home to play the game.

So the chances of being drawn as the away team is 1/2

I understand the probability of them being drawn as the away team 17 times in a row is 1/2 to the power of 17 but how do you find out the answer if they are drawn out 15 times away and twice at home.

I suppose the question could also be 'what is the probability of getting 15 heads and two tails after flipping a coin 17 times'

Thanks

Comment: The answer to the "equivalent" question is $\frac{\binom{17}{2}}{2^{17}}=0.103759765625$ percent. Nevertheless, I doubt it is really equivalent, because I don't quite understand the original question to begin with (please rephrase it with all the necessary details).

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the probability of getting exactly AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHH where A is away and H is home, and then multiply by the number of ways to arrange this. The probability of getting that exact sequence is just $\frac{1}{{2}^{17}}$. The number of ways to arrange it is $\frac{17!}{15!2!}$, so we get $$\frac{1}{{2}^{17}}*\frac{17!}{15!2!} = \frac{17}{16384}=0.104\%$$